# Why is this Rails migration giving a 'no such table' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

In a new Rails 6 project, I have a table named object_classes with a column named ClassList_id. From schema.rb:

```
 create_table "object_classes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "ClassList_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["ClassList_id"], name: "index_object_classes_on_ClassList_id"
  end
```

I've realized that the column should be named class_list_id to conform with Rails expected naming convention. Therefore, I have generated a new migration:

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    rename_column :object_classes, :ClassList_id, :class_list_id
  end
end
```

However, when I run this migration, I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash -c "env RBENV_VERSION=2.6.1 /home/asfarley/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv exec bundle exec ruby /home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring rails 'db:migrate'"
== 20200716060501 FixColumnName: migrating ====================================
-- rename_column(:object_classes, :ClassList_id, :class_list_id)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.ClassLists
/home/asfarley/imgseq/db/migrate/20200716060501_fix_column_name.rb:3:in `change'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring:15:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.ClassLists
/home/asfarley/imgseq/db/migrate/20200716060501_fix_column_name.rb:3:in `change'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring:15:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.ClassLists
/home/asfarley/imgseq/db/migrate/20200716060501_fix_column_name.rb:3:in `change'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/asfarley/imgseq/bin/spring:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm looking for an explanation that addresses specifically what is wrong here, so that I can understand how to avoid this in the future.

Comment: that's not a proper symbol, try this... rename_column :object_classes, "ClassList_id", :class_list_id

Comment: @dbugger interesting, I should have tried that, but I already fixed it by changing my migration a different way. I will keep your suggestion in mind for future cases of undefined foreign-key constraints.

Comment: @dbugger actually, based on the fact that my migration worked after removing the foreign key, I believe that the undefined symbol is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know whether the fault is Rails or SQLite, but the issue seems to be that I had a foreign key defined for my object_classes table pointing to a table that didn't exist. With this migration, I was able to fix the foreign key constraint and rename the column:

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :object_classes, :ClassLists
    rename_column :object_classes, :ClassList_id, :class_list_id
    add_foreign_key :object_classes, :class_lists
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is ok so the error must be a reserved name error. may try and remove the column and creating the column again, watch out for capital letters on migrations for they can unnecessarily complicate your code. try this:

```
rails g migration RemoveClassListIdFromObjectClasses
```

that will created a migration kinda like this:

```
def drop 
    remove column :object_classes, :class_lis_id
end
```

and then run

```
rails g migration AddClassListIdToObjectClasses
```

the migration should look something like this:

```
def change
    add_column :object_classes, :class_list_id
end
```

remember to add the data type and anything else you may need.
there you can check the migration it created and you can change it to maybe add the data type or maybe change the capitalization of the column and you will be set to go.

note: if it works i would appreciate if you accepted the answer, Thanks!

Comment: It wasn't a reserved name error; it was that a foreign key pointed to a non-existant table. However, I did end up fixing this myself so I can't confirm whether this approach would also have resolved the issue. It's possible that your approach of deleting the column would have the side-effect of deleting the foreign key, which may work as an alternative to my approach.

Comment: Im glad to hear you resolved it. It wouldnt be a problem because you can easily add the foreing key again to the migration and nothing else would break.